# cron job is not running

Tags: bash, scripts, cron

I'm beginner learning to set up cron job.

I have made this sample bash script to schedule in my ubuntu system

test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo touch /home/masteradmin/google.txt
```

`sudo chmod +x test.sh`

typed `crontab -e`
made an entry like this in the file

`37 00 * * * /bin/bash /myFiles/test.sh 2>&1 > /myFiles/teest.txt`

and was checking for it to create a new files in the specified path, but it is not executing.

Comment: Don't try to gain elevated privileges by using `sudo` from *within* a cron job - use `sudo crontab -e` to place the job in `root`'s crontab. As well, you probably want the redirections the other way around `> /myFiles/teest.txt 2>&1`

Comment: if you manually do `sudo touch /home/masteradmin/google.txt`, does it run right away or do you need to type your password or have some kind of interaction?

Comment: @steeldriver thanks for your reply and sorry for late. I have tried it with sudo -i and and changed the path of it as said by you but  the cron job is not working. it is not running

Comment: @EduardoTrápani yes it has asked me for pwd. do i have to get the permission for that folder?

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` will not be able to ask for a password when it runs inside `cron`. You have at least two solutions:

- run the command in root's crontab, not the user's. You will not need sudo then. (as @steeldriver said in the first comment).
- setup `sudo` so that it doesn't ask for a pasword for that particular command. [This page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers) explains it pretty well.